# Java: vaadin web application

Tags: web, vaadin, http-post

I want to test my vaadin web application with google chrome browser and rest console. I want to send post-requests to vaadin-application, but i can't find adress of http-request listener. May be someone knows?

Comment: Vaadin does not use REST for it's communication, look at the Vaadin testbench for automated testing. https://vaadin.com/de/add-ons/testbench

Comment: thanks for your help. Rest-console it is name of util which sends post-request to an address and i read https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/157626 and understand that data between applet and browser sends via post-method and i want to send my information the same

Comment: Vaadin is not intended to be used as REST (Or receiving post/get requests)
Just create a separate servlet for this (Otherwise you will also stumble into the problem of managing the vaadin security protocoll)

Comment: Is your question answered?